# Write active decorator DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, rubygems, decorator

I'm using ActiveDecorator: https://github.com/amatsuda/active_decorator

On writing my `UserDecorator`, I find it overlap a lot. Just decorate the `datetime` but I have to repeat writing decorator a lot.

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module UserDecorator
  def created_at_datetime
    created_at&.strftime '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
  end

  def confirmed_at_datetime
    confirmed_at&.strftime '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
  end

  def locked_at_datetime
    locked_at&.strftime '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
  end

  def current_sign_in_at_datetime
    current_sign_in_at&.strftime '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
  end

  def last_sign_in_at_datetime
    last_sign_in_at&.strftime '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
  end
end
```

And guess what, on my `AdminDecorator` I have the exact same fields. Do I have to copy all of these again to AdminDecorator?
Any advice guys?

Ref: https://github.com/amatsuda/active_decorator/issues/104

Comment: You have `%Y/%m/%m` in your example code, you probably want `%Y/%m/%d`

Comment: Nice catch! Thanks I updated!

Answer (score 5):

I don't use `active_decorator`, but I think I would be tempted to create a `DatetimeDecorator`, something like:

```
module DatetimeDecorator

  %i(
    created_at
    confirmed_at
    locked_at
    current_sign_in_at
    last_sign_in_at
  ).each do |attr_sym|
    define_method("#{attr_sym}_datetime") do 
      send(attr_sym)&.strftime '%Y/%m/%m %H:%M:%S'
    end
  end

end
```

Whenever you include this module, you'll get the five methods you previously defined in `UserDecorator` each of which uses the same formatting code.

Now, to get that module included, use the `included` hook. Something like:

```
module UserDecorator

  self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do 
      include DatetimeDecorator
    end
  end

end

module AdminDecorator

  self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do 
      include DatetimeDecorator
    end
  end

end
```

Now your `UserDecorator` and your `AdminDecorator` both have the five methods you previously defined in `UserDecorator`.

This is untested, so you might need to fiddle with it a bit.

Comment: Wow thanks for your detailed answer! Lemme digest it!

Comment: Sure thing. I've never seen this gem before, and rolled my own a while back using SimpleDelegator. Maybe I'll poke around this one now that you've pointed it out.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite similar to [jvillian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56845036/477037) and [truongnm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56846623/477037).

I usually write little DSL methods to add repeating methods, something like this:

```
module DateFormatter
  DEFAULT_FORMAT = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'

  def add_formatter(attribute, format: DEFAULT_FORMAT)
    define_method("#{attribute}_datetime") do
      public_send(attribute)&.strftime(format)
    end
  end
end
```

`add_formatter` is a class method that defines an instance method based on the given arguments. Having `format` as an optional argument is just an example.

As a class method, `add_format` can be called right inside the class body like this:

```
module UserDecorator
  extend DateFormatter

  add_formatter :created_at
  add_formatter :confirmed_at, format: '%A %-d, %Y'
  add_formatter :locked_at
  add_formatter :current_sign_in_at
  add_formatter :last_sign_in_at
end
```

The `UserDecorator` module ends up having various new method:

```
UserDecorator.instance_methods
#=> [
#     :confirmed_at_datetime,
#     :locked_at_datetime,
#     :current_sign_in_at_datetime,
#     :last_sign_in_at_datetime,
#     :created_at_datetime
#   ]
```

They can be called as usual:

```
class TestUser
  include UserDecorator

  def created_at
    Time.new(2019, 7, 2, 11, 53)
  end

  def confirmed_at
    Time.new(2019, 7, 2, 11, 53)
  end
end

u = TestUser.new
u.created_at_datetime
#=> "2019/07/02 11:53:00"

u.confirmed_at_datetime
#=> "Tuesday 2, 2019"
```

Since you are using Rails, you might want to incorporate its [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) pattern.

Comment: Since you mention about `ActiveSupoprt::Concern`, can you said abit more about it? Thanks!

Comment: @truongnm it makes adding class methods and instance methods from other modules a bit easier. Following the conventions, you can simply `include YourMixin` (as opposed to `include ThisModule` and `extend ThatModule`) and it will handle the rest. Just check out the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).

Comment: What do you think if we use `method_missing`?

Comment: @truongnm `method_missing` comes with some processing overhead. For a fixed (or small) number of methods, I prefer generating them. It also allows you to enumerate the methods (as shown in the example) and to use auto completion in IRB.

Answer (score 1):

I could use some meta code like these but I can't solve the exact same fields at `AdminDecorator`. Which mean I still have to copy paste below function to `AdminDecorator`:

```rb
module UserDecorator
  DATETIME_DECORATOR_FIELDS = %w[created_at confirmed_at locked_at current_sign_in last_sign_in_at].freeze

  DATETIME_DECORATOR_FIELDS.each do |field|
    define_method("#{field}_datetime") do |format = nil|
      return send(field)&.strftime(format) if format

      send(field)&.strftime '%Y/%m/%m %H:%M:%S'
    end
  end
end
```

This will create method accept params format or not:

```rb
User.first.created_at_datetime #=> "2019/06/06 16:18:02"

User.first.created_at_datetime "%Y/%m/%m" #=> "2019/06/06"
```